# How to break down an element in a list into different elements?

Tags: python

I have this list in Python:

```
Groceries= ['Grapes: 8', 'Apples: 2 Bananas: 3 Peaches: 5', 'Orange: 4']
```

How can I segregate the second element in the list into three elements so that my list becomes:

```
Groceries= ['Grapes: 8', 'Apples: 2', 'Bananas: 3', 'Peaches: 5', 'Orange: 4']
```

Keep in mind that I will need to do this for many different lists with the same variables (grapes, apples, bananas, peaches and oranges) but different assigned values.

Comment: Use `split()` to split each string at whitespace. Then `join()` each pair of elements back together to get the `name: number` strings.

Comment: Or you could use a regular expression that matches `name: number`, and use `re.findall()` in each string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one list comprehension approach using `re.findall` along with a flattening operation:

```py
Groceries = ['Grapes: 8', 'Apples: 2 Bananas: 3 Peaches: 5', 'Orange: 4']
output = [i for sub in [re.findall(r'\w+: \d+', x) for x in Groceries] for i in sub]
print(output)

# ['Grapes: 8', 'Apples: 2', 'Bananas: 3', 'Peaches: 5', 'Orange: 4']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the re library, this is a viable solution:

```py
res = []
Groceries= ['Grapes: 8', 'Apples: 2 Bananas: 3 Peaches: 5', 'Orange: 4']
for val in Groceries:
    space_split = val.split()
    for x in range(int(len(space_split)/2)):
        res.append(space_split[2*x]+" "+space_split[2*x+1])
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]*[:]\s[0-9])')
finalList = list()

Groceries= ['Grapes: 8', 'Apples: 2 Bananas: 3 Peaches: 5', 'Orange: 4']

for grocery in Groceries:
    matchObject = regex.findall(grocery)
    for matched in matchObject:
        finalList.append(matched)

print(finalList)
```

**Remember the zen of python:**

*Simple is better than complex.*